# How to get disjoint dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I drop common age from my data frame?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define the data
dataA = [['zebra', 34], ['zebra', 20]]
dataB = [['zebra', 36], ['zebra', 20]]

# Create DataFrames
dfA = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns=['animal', 'ageM']).set_index('animal')
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dataB, columns=['animal', 'ageO']).set_index('animal')

# Left join dfB onto dfA
joined_df = dfA.join(dfB, how='left')
```

My resulting data frame should be:

```py
result = [['zebra',34,36]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please briefly describe in the question what is the rationale behind the expected output *i.e.*, how is the expected output generated from `dfA` and `dfB`? You can use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77873191/edit) option to directly add this information in the question.

Comment: Could you please clarify your expected outcome for a slightly different scenario? Suppose `dataA` has an additional row with `['zebra', 36]`, and `dataB` has an additional row with `['zebra', 10]`. In this case, the age `36` appears in both `dataA` and `dataB`, but not in matching pairs. Would you expect the row with age `36` in `dataA` to be removed because the same age appears in `dataB`, even though it's in a **different row**?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) on one column versus the other and combine the two boolean masks with `|`:

```
m = joined_df['ageM'] # assigning short names for clarity
o = joined_df['ageO']

out = joined_df[~(m.isin(o) | o.isin(m))]
```

Or:

```
out = joined_df[~(joined_df['ageM'].isin(joined_df['ageO'])
                 |joined_df['ageO'].isin(joined_df['ageM'])
                 )]
```

Output:

```
        ageM  ageO
animal            
zebra     34    36
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `concat` the two dataframes together then filter the results.  Like this:

```
pd.concat([dfA, dfB], axis=1).query('ageM != ageO')
```

Output:

```
        ageM  ageO
animal            
zebra     34    36
```

There are a lot of ways to achieve your desired dataframe, just that the logic isn't clear, imho.